# Copy module to another module maven multi-modules

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to copy a sub-module to another module without any errors while running the application

here is my structure:

```
+ -- MyMainProject
     + -- application           
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- domain                
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- bootloader            
     |     `src/main/java
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- infrastructure        <- infrastructure module (has 3 modules)
          + -- infrastructure 1          
          |     `  --  pom.xml
          + -- infrastructure 2          
          |     `  --  pom.xml
          + -- infrastructure 3          <- move this module to application module
          |     `  --  pom.xml
     | -- pom.xml
```

So what I'm trying to do is to move sub-module `infrastructure 3` to `application` module and then my application module will have infrastructure 3 as a sub-module without any errors.
I'm using intellij, any suggestion please

Comment: You'll have to share your POMs. We can give you the simple answer, but there are many constraints that we do not know about.

Answer (score 1):

In your root `pom.xml` you probably have `<modules/>` tag, so what you need is to copy `infrastructure 3` directory onto the same level with `application` and include `infrastructure 3` into mentioned `<modules/>` tag.

With IDEA you can move directory with its contents with F6. After the changes are done simply press Ctrl+Shift+O to reimport maven project, so IDEA will restructure its auxiliary files and indexes.